# Not able to get rid of duplicates and sum quantity

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am working on a SQL statement in order to get create a cron job to get a csv file regarding our product stock and returns. However when I run it even though I am summing the qty, I still get duplicates on the sku code and it looks like it is not summing the return qty.

Please see the code below, thanks a lot.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.part
,   p.identifier
,   p.descr
,   supl.full_name AS supplier
,   pgrp.descr AS groupd
,   fam.descr AS family
,   pt.part_cost AS Cost_GBP
,   ISNULL((
            SELECT
                SUM(qty - ISNULL(qty_received, 0))
            FROM
                pord_line AS pl
            WHERE
                status < 31
                AND p.part = pl.part
                AND qty - ISNULL(qty_received, 0) > 0
           ), 0) AS OnPO
,   (
     SELECT TOP 1
        pb.bcode
     FROM
        part_barc pb WITH (NOLOCK)
     WHERE
        pb.part = p.part
        AND pb.bcode LIKE '5%'
        AND LEN(pb.bcode) = 13
     ORDER BY
        pb.last_updated DESC
    ) AS EAN
,   (
     SELECT TOP 1
        v.price
     FROM
        vprice_list v
     WHERE
        v.part = p.part
        AND v.volume = 1
        AND v.price_list = 'WEB UK'
    ) AS RRP_GBP
,   (
     SELECT TOP 1
        v.price
     FROM
        vprice_list v
     WHERE
        v.part = p.part
        AND v.volume = 1
        AND v.price_list = 'WEB US'
    ) AS RRP_USD
,   p.status
,   p.obs_code
,   (CASE WHEN p.obs_code = 0 THEN 0
          ELSE 100
     END) AS obslink
,   ISNULL(RTRIM(dbo.[fn_get_attr_value]('WEB', 'TEXT2', p.part, 1)), '') AS long_descr
,   t.Main_Store_Total_Stock
,   t.Main_Store_Allocated
,   f.Assay_Office_Total_Stock
,   f.Assay_Office_Allocated
,   g.Consigment_Stock_Total_Stock
,   g.Consigment_Stock_Allocated
,   h.Customer_Returns_Total_Stock
,   h.Customer_Returns_Allocated
,   j.Despatch_Total_Stock
,   j.Despatch_Allocated
,   k.Goods_in_Total_Stock
,   k.Goods_in_Allocated
,   l.Harrods_Total_Stock
,   l.Harrods_Allocated
,   m.Inspection_Total_Stock
,   m.Inspection_Allocated
,   n.Liberty_Total_Stock
,   n.Liberty_Allocated
,   o.Repair_Store_Total_Stock
,   o.Repair_Store_Allocated
,   q.Return_from_Supplier_Total_Stock
,   q.Return_from_Supplier_Allocated
,   r.Selfridges_Trafford_Total_Stock
,   r.Selfridges_Trafford_Allocated
,   u.Selfridges_Oxford_Total_Stock
,   u.Selfridges_Oxford_Allocated
,   w.Supplier_Returns_Total_Stock
,   w.Supplier_Returns_Allocated
,   x.UK_Press_Total_Stock
,   x.UK_Press_Allocated
,   y.US_Press_Total_Stock
,   y.US_Press_Allocated
FROM
    part p
    LEFT JOIN part_plan pp1
    ON pp1.part = p.part
    LEFT JOIN part_pnar pnar
    ON pnar.part = p.part
    LEFT JOIN pgrp
    ON pgrp.prod_group = p.prod_group
    LEFT JOIN faml_pgrp fam
    ON fam.prod_family = pgrp.prod_family
    LEFT JOIN sgrp
    ON sgrp.sales_group = p.sales_group
    LEFT JOIN supl
    ON supl.supplier = pp1.prefer_supplier
    LEFT JOIN part_trad pt
    ON p.part = pt.part
    LEFT JOIN part_bins pp
    ON p.part = pp.part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Main_Store_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Main_Store_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Main Store'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS t
    ON p.part = t.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Assay_Office_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Assay_Office_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Assay Office'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS f
    ON p.part = f.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Consigment_Stock_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Consigment_Stock_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Consigment Stock'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS g
    ON p.part = g.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Customer_Returns_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Customer_Returns_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Customer Returns'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS h
    ON p.part = h.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Despatch_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Despatch_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Despatch'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS j
    ON p.part = j.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Goods_in_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Goods_in_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Goods In'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS k
    ON p.part = k.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Harrods_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Harrods_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Harrods'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS l
    ON p.part = l.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Inspection_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Inspection_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Inspection'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS m
    ON p.part = m.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Liberty_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Liberty_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Liberty'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS n
    ON p.part = n.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Repair_Store_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Repair_Store_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Repair Store'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS o
    ON p.part = o.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Return_from_Supplier_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Return_from_Supplier_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Return from Supplier'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS q
    ON p.part = q.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Selfridges_Trafford_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Selfridges_Trafford_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Selfidges Trafford'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS r
    ON p.part = r.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Selfridges_Oxford_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Selfridges_Oxford_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Selfridges Oxford'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS u
    ON p.part = u.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS Supplier_Returns_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS Supplier_Returns_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'Supplier Returns'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS w
    ON p.part = w.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS UK_Press_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS UK_Press_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'UK Press'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS x
    ON p.part = x.Part
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT
                dbo.part.part AS Part
               ,SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) AS US_Press_Total_Stock
               ,dbo.stor.descr AS Stor
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty AS US_Press_Allocated
               FROM
                dbo.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.part_bins
                ON dbo.part.part = dbo.part_bins.part
                INNER JOIN dbo.stor
                ON dbo.part_bins.store = dbo.stor.store
                   AND dbo.stor.descr = 'US Press'
               GROUP BY
                dbo.part.part
               ,dbo.stor.descr
               ,dbo.part_bins.allocated_qty
              ) AS y
    ON p.part = y.Part
GROUP BY
    p.identifier
,   p.part
,   p.descr
,   supl.full_name
,   pgrp.descr
,   fam.descr
,   pp.qty
,   pt.part_cost
,   pp.allocated_qty
,   p.status
,   p.obs_code
,   t.Main_Store_Total_Stock
,   t.Main_Store_Allocated
,   f.Assay_Office_Total_Stock
,   f.Assay_Office_Allocated
,   g.Consigment_Stock_Total_Stock
,   g.Consigment_Stock_Allocated
,   h.Customer_Returns_Total_Stock
,   h.Customer_Returns_Allocated
,   j.Despatch_Total_Stock
,   j.Despatch_Allocated
,   k.Goods_in_Total_Stock
,   k.Goods_in_Allocated
,   l.Harrods_Total_Stock
,   l.Harrods_Allocated
,   m.Inspection_Total_Stock
,   m.Inspection_Allocated
,   n.Liberty_Total_Stock
,   n.Liberty_Allocated
,   o.Repair_Store_Total_Stock
,   o.Repair_Store_Allocated
,   q.Return_from_Supplier_Total_Stock
,   q.Return_from_Supplier_Allocated
,   r.Selfridges_Trafford_Total_Stock
,   r.Selfridges_Trafford_Allocated
,   u.Selfridges_Oxford_Total_Stock
,   u.Selfridges_Oxford_Allocated
,   w.Supplier_Returns_Total_Stock
,   w.Supplier_Returns_Allocated
,   x.UK_Press_Total_Stock
,   x.UK_Press_Allocated
,   y.US_Press_Total_Stock
,   y.US_Press_Allocated;
```

These are some of the duplicates I am getting with differents qty for return (SUM(dbo.part_bins.qty) as Supplier_Returns_Total_Stock)

```
29620RMGR50 D29620SZ5   Morganite Tearoom Ring Rose Size UK J/US 5  Thien Po    Fine / Fao  Astley Clarke   299.6700    1.0000  NULL    1450.000000 2250.000000 20  0   0   14 carat rose gold morganite and diamond ring   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2.0000  0.0000  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1.0000  1.0000  NULL    NULL    0.0000  0.0000  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

29620RMGR50 D29620SZ5   Morganite Tearoom Ring Rose Size UK J/US 5  Thien Po    Fine / Fao  Astley Clarke   299.6700    1.0000  NULL    1450.000000 2250.000000 20  0   0   14 carat rose gold morganite and diamond ring   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2.0000  0.0000  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2.0000  0.0000  NULL    NULL    0.0000  0.0000  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Do you really expect us to go through that much of a code?

Comment: Hi Lamak, Thanks a lot for your help. This is high level SQL programming so I expect to find some gurus on the network if possible? I apologise for any inconvenience this may cause to you...Thanks very much indeed :-)

Comment: @user3005677 The issue is not getting a guru or not (and Lamak I think qualifies). It's that you're dumping a huge amount of code and asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: Start from the beginning with selecting from `part`. Add one table at a time to your query, and run that query, until you get to the `JOIN` that results in duplications. No sane person is going to go through all that hideously badly formatted code.

Comment: Somewhere toward the end, you have 1 vs 2 and 1 vs 0. I'm guessing you're wanting some sort of aggregation (sum) on those columns. I think it's returns

Comment: Hi Billinkc, Thanks a lot for your input and help. Basically I am modifying the code that another company put for us but it was no doing what we wanted so I decided to go through the WHOLE code (Even though it's bad formatted as advised on previous replies) I am now amending it to our custom need.My apologies to Lamak, JNK and Mark.I thought that despite of DOING MY JOB,I could find some advise here as Billinkc's one.I don't intend to get other people to do my job or hurt anyone's feelings,it's simply that I want to get some ideas from anyone on this network...the same way I helped others here

Comment: Hi Guys, I found the solution. Basically the reason why I was getting the duplicates is because the returns were from different locations (stores - bin) So what I did was to associate the stores and the bins properly in order to get rid of the duplicates and get the aggregated sum right and the code is working very well now. Once again, I apologise for any inconvenience this ticket may have caused.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically the reason why I was getting the duplicates is because the returns were from different locations (stores - bin) So what I did was to associate the stores and the bins properly in order to get rid of the duplicates and get the aggregated sum right and the code is working very well now. Once again, I apologise for any inconvenience this ticket may have caused.